# Node.js Facebook API

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

I am new to Node.js and I am having difficulties. I just wanted someone to explain where I am going wrong. I am trying to get stats from my Facebook chats and I wanted to used this API [call](https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api/blob/master/DOCS.md#getThreadInfo). This is the basic code I have written.

```
var login = require("facebook-chat-api");

login({email: "Email", password: "Password"}, function callback (err, api) {
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    var threadID = chatNo;
    output = api.getThreadInfo(threadNo)
    console.log(output)

});
```

When I run this on Node.js the output is "undefined", I cant tell if its because the API call didn't work, or because I am trying to output it incorrectly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
 [Output of Node.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhK7L.png)

Comment: Anything that uses user credentials directly to login to Facebook is _wrong_ to begin with - because that is against Facebook ToS. If you want to interact with Facebook in any way - use their API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the callback of `getThreadInfo` like this

```
login({email: "Email", password: "Password"}, function callback (err, api) {
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    var threadID = chatNo;
    api.getThreadInfo(threadID, function (err, info) {
        console.log(err, info);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, it works perfectly.